# Display an image from Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, firebase-storage

I'm trying to show an image that is store in Firebase. I've tried this code but it gives me this error *The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.* This error is give from the **{** at `builder: (context, snapshot){`

How can i fix the code?

**[EDIT]** that code below doesn't give more error, but it doen't show the image

**Dependencies version:**

- firebase_core: ^1.3.0
- firebase_analytics: ^7.0.1
- firebase_auth: ^1.4.1
- cloud_firestore: ^2.2.2
- firebase_storage: ^8.1.3

```
InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StantonPlanet())); //Pyro
    },
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
      height: 180,
      child: Card(
        color: blue,
        semanticContainer: true,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getImage(context, 'pyro.png'),
          builder: (context, snapshot){

              if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
                return Container(
                 child: snapshot.data,
                );
              }

              if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
               return Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
              }

              return Container();

          }
        ),
        //Image.asset('assets/images/systems/pyro.png', fit: BoxFit.fill,),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        elevation: 0,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      ),
    ),
  ),//close InkWell
```

**This is the class**

```
class FireStorageService extends ChangeNotifier{
  FireStorageService();
  static Future<dynamic> loadImage(BuildContext context, String Image) async{
    return await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(Image).getDownloadURL();
  }
}
```

**This is the future**

```
 Future<Widget> _getImage(BuildContext context, String imageName) async{
    Image image = '' as Image;
    await FireStorageService.loadImage(context, imageName).then((value) {
     image =Image.network(
       value.toString(),
       fit: BoxFit.fill,
     );
    });
    return image;
  }
```

Comment: You only specify what widget to show when the ConnectionState is done. You will also need to specify another widget that is shown while the ConnectionState is not done e.g. a loading indicator.

Comment: edited, 0 errors, but it dosn't show the image.

Comment: Check whether you receive the correct image URL.  print 'value'  & see

Comment: it does not print anything, it is as if it does not see the print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed

```
InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StantonPlanet())); //Pyro
    },
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
      height: 180,
      child: Card(
        color: blue,
        semanticContainer: true,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getImage(context, 'pyro.png'),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
              if(snapshot.hasError){
                 return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }
              if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
                return Container(
                 child: snapshot.data,
                );
              }

              if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
               return Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
              }

              return Container();

          }
        ),
        //Image.asset('assets/images/systems/pyro.png', fit: BoxFit.fill,),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        elevation: 0,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      ),
    ),
  ),//close InkWell
```

**This is the class**

```
class FireStorageService extends ChangeNotifier{
  FireStorageService();
  static Future<String> loadImage(BuildContext context, String image) async{
    return await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(image).getDownloadURL();
  }
}
```

**This is the future**

```
 Future<Widget> _getImage(BuildContext context, String imageName) async{
    Image image ;
    final value = await FireStorageService.loadImage(context, imageName);
    image =Image.network(
      value.toString(),
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    );
    return image;
  }
```